# how to add other component (html tag, js, and css) in form module

Tags: forms, 8

Suppose I have the following code.

```
class customCreateForm extends FormBase {

/* code code code... */

  public function getFormId() { /* code */ }
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['label'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('title'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Your title'),
      '#default_value' => "",
      '#size' => 10,
      '#maxlength' => 8,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    /* code code code... */
    return form;
  }
  /* code code code... */
}
```

I can understand how to add a form element, but how can I add HTML markup or JavaScript?

For example, I want to add the following in my custom form.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bla...">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="something" class="something">
        <img src="bla" /> 
    </div>
<table id="something" class="something"><tr><td>aaa</td></tr></table>

<script>
/* code code code */
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=aaaa&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

you should add a library like this :

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/mylibrary';
```

Create mylibrary.libraries.yml file with the content :

```
mylibrary:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/my-css.css: {}
  js:
    js/my-js.js: {}
```

more documentation: https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets

Comment: If you want to add more than one javascript file, do you need two js: sections or can you put them both under the same one?

Answer (score 2):

Add html content with #markup type form field for example,

```
$form['html-content'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<div class="your-class"><h2>your content</h2></div>,
);
```

Form API have an option to add javascript and css with #attached option,
we could add as library,

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'module/library-name';
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Render API overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.2.x). What reported there is also valid in the case of a form, which is a render array nonetheless.

- Libraries, JavaScript settings, feeds, HTML `<head>` tags and HTML `<head>` links are attached to elements using the `#attached` property.

  ```
  $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/jquery';
  ```

```
    $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['foo'] = 'bar';
```

```
    $build['#attached']['feed'][] = [$url, $this->t('Feed title')];
```

- To output generic HTML markup you use:

  - `#type` or `#theme`, which are preferable when the output is complex
  - `#markup`, which is preferable when the output is simple, considering also that its output is filtered by [`\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::filterAdmin()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.p); in this case, if you need to output one of tags that is not listed in [`Xss::$adminTags`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.p), you need to use `#allowed_tags`

    ```
    $build[
      '#type' => 'view',
      '#name' => $name,
      '#display_id' => $display_id,
      '#arguments' => $args,
    ];
    ```

```
        $form['contacts'] = array(
          '#type' => 'table',
          '#caption' => $this->t('Sample Table'),
          '#header' => array($this->t('Name'), $this->t('Phone')),
        );

        for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {
          $form['contacts'][$i]['name'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
            '#title_display' => 'invisible',
          );

          $form['contacts'][$i]['phone'] = array(
            '#type' => 'tel',
            '#title' => $this->t('Phone'),
            '#title_display' => 'invisible',
          );
        }
```

```
        $output['filtered_string'] = array(
          '#markup' => '<audio controls><source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg"><source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio tag.</audio>',
          '#allowed_tags' => ['audio', 'source'],
        );
```